# Creating two separate Boxplots for yes/no variable on same plot using ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-science

I am trying to create a boxplot where on the x axis there is a binary 1/2 variable. When I create my boxplot and the loop using ggplot I just get one big boxplot that is centered at 1.5 when instead I want a boxplot at 1 and a boxplot at 2. I am new to this so any help and additional reading would be appreciated. Below is the code.

```
myboxplot <- function(mydata=ivf_dataset, myexposure, myoutcome  )
  {
  bp <- ggplot(mydata, aes_(as.name(myexposure), as.name(myoutcome))) +
     geom_boxplot() 
      print(bp)
  }
 myboxplot(myexposure = "ART_CURRENT", myoutcome = "H19_DMR_mean")
```

Comment: See also these answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/50726130/786542 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/49870618/786542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do what you want.
The trick is to `get` the values of the variables you want to plot, since you pass them to the function as character strings.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(7153)
ivf_dataset <- data.frame(
  ART_CURRENT = sample.int(2, 100, TRUE),
  H19_DMR_mean = rnorm(100)
)

myboxplot <- function(mydata=ivf_dataset, myexposure, myoutcome  ){
  bp <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x = as.factor(get(myexposure)), y = get(myoutcome))) +
    geom_boxplot() 
  print(bp)
}
myboxplot(myexposure = "ART_CURRENT", myoutcome = "H19_DMR_mean")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that does work however do you have any good readings on how the "get" function works?

Comment: @DillonLloyd Well, there is `help("get")` and the source code, R is open source. But I must admit to never having read it (the source).

Answer (score 0):

```
myboxplot <- function(mydata=ivf_dataset, myexposure, myoutcome  )
  {
  bp <- ggplot(mydata, aes_(myexposure, as.factor(myoutcome))) +
     geom_boxplot() 
      print(bp)
  }
 myboxplot(myexposure = "ART_CURRENT", myoutcome = "H19_DMR_mean")
```

If you want to plot multiple boxplot based on the value of a variable, that variable must be a factor!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Like I said, I am new at this so in order to make the variable a factor do I need to do that by modifying my dataset or is there an easy way to do it within the function?

Comment: check my answer