# knitr printing list of graphs in .Rnw

Tags: r, knitr, tidyverse

I want to print list of graphs throw `.Rnw`. Wonder how to accomplish the task.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\begin{figure}[H]
<< label = Plot >>=
library(tidyverse)
Ys <- c("disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec")

Plots <- 
  Ys %>% 
  map(function(y)
    ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = mpg, y = y)) +
      geom_point(aes_string(y = y))
  )

print(Plots)
@
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using knitr (not Sweave)?  If so, knitr [can save the graphs as files too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992239/knitr-include-figures-in-report-and-output-figures-to-separate-files).

Comment: I'm using knitr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<< label = Plot >>=
library(tidyverse)
Ys <- c("disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec")

Plots <- 
  Ys %>% 
  map(function(y)
    ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = mpg, y = y)) +
      geom_point(aes_string(y = y))
  )

@

<<results=tex,echo=FALSE, >>=

for(i in 1:length(Plots)){
file=paste("myfile", i, ".png", sep="")
png(file, res = 80)
print(Plots[[i]])
dev.off()
cat(  "\\begin{figure}\n\\includegraphics{", file, "}\n\n\\end{figure}\n", sep="")
}
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

### It is really advisable to switch to `knitr`

#### Putting 4 plots in one

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{figure}

<< label = Plot , fig=TRUE,results=hide>>=
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
Ys <- c("disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec")

plotLlist<-list()
for (i in 1:length(Ys)) {
  plotLlist[[i]]<- ggplot(data = mtcars,  aes_string(x = "mpg", y = Ys[i])) +
  geom_point(aes_string(y = Ys[i]))

}
print(grid.arrange(grobs =plotLlist[1:4], nrow = 2))

@
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @imi for your answer. This is not working for me. Any thoughts.

Comment: any error? or it is about the layout? what is your operating system?

Comment: Working now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @imi for the nice solution. Would appreciate if you guide me how to put four figures in one page. Thanks

Comment: Following page will help you. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the variations on `purrr::walk` to silently map over the list of plots and save them with `ggsave`. `walk2` maps over two lists, or `iwalk` maps over a list and its names. `iwalk` is really simple if you give the plot list names; the way I did it here is a little awkward, but in the wild, such as when plotting from a data frame that's been split, or with a vector that already has names, it could be different.

`aes_string` is used for creating `aes` calls programmatically, but it's being deprecated in favor of tidy eval; one example of this is in the `aes` docs, but I also was reminded of how to do it by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50726130/5325862).

I first name the vector, with its own values as its names. Then I map over it and apply a function that takes a string `y` and creates a symbol of it using `rlang::sym`. This allows me to use tidy eval to create a bare column name with `!!y_sum`.

```r
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/50726130/5325862
Plots <- Ys %>%
  setNames(., nm = .) %>%
  map(function(y) {
    y_sym <- rlang::sym(y)

    ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = !!y_sym)) +
      geom_point()
  })
```

Example of one plot in the list, which can be accessed by name:

```r
Plots$hp
```

[image]

Then to save the plots, `iwalk` over using the names to create filenames. You can add additional parameters to `ggsave`, such as dimensions and resolution.

```r
Plots %>%
  iwalk(~ggsave(filename = sprintf("%s_vs_mpg.png", .y), plot = .x))
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```

You can do everything in one step if you need: map along to make plots and save in a single function. I went with the approach of saving the plots to a list, since that's what you did in the question, and that allows you to pull up individual plots in your document, rather than only saving them as files.

Comment: Thanks @camille for your answer. I'm still not able to get it correctly. Please see my edits and suggest any solution. Thanks

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? And what's the reason for not using Rmarkdown, which should be able to do this more simply?

Answer (score 1):

This will create the five pngs in the working directory, (which is the location of the Rnw file, unless you've modified it with something like `opts_knit$set(root.dir='../../')`).

```
Ys %>% 
  purrr::iwalk(
    ~ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = "mpg", y = .x)) +
        geom_point() +
        ggsave(filename = .y, device = "png")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks @wibeasley for your answer. I'm still not able to get it correctly. Please see my edits and suggest any solution. Thanks